# Development of a blackberry

Tags: blackberry-10

Do you think whether to continue to pursue the development of a Blackberry and using the native sdk? What are the pluses of this way? With the release of blackberry 10.3 will complete podderzhaka android application, so I do not know what to do. I never developed under android. Maybe someone knows what are the main advantages of developing using native sdk port compared with android applications?

I'm a big sorrow. I developed a blaskberry for 4 years and now I do not know what to do.

Comment: You can learn android easily, if you developed for BB Java.

Comment: Not the problem. The question is whether to continue and further develop a Blackberry? If applications are developed and the use of native code is no better applications for android, the choice is clear. I will start to develop a android (at least due to the fact that in version 10.3 will Amazone store. And potential buyers more). So I asked the question. What are the pluses in applications developed using native code